# Calculation of SHA1 Digest or a Xades SignedProperties is not working

Tags: c#, xml, digest

I have the following XML File :

```
<xad:SignedProperties Id="Sig_20151117_172752_SP">
                <xad:SignedSignatureProperties>
                    <xad:SigningTime>2015-11-17T16:27:59Z</xad:SigningTime>
                    <xad:SigningCertificate>
                        <xad:Cert>
                            <xad:CertDigest>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>vkVMqVMRsiSbo3Zgvk9sTfVtRDs=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </xad:CertDigest>
                            <xad:IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=CERTEUROPE ADVANCED CA V4, OU=0002 434202180, O=Certeurope, C=FR</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>747583</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </xad:IssuerSerial>
                        </xad:Cert>
                    </xad:SigningCertificate>
                    <xad:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                        <xad:SignaturePolicyId>
                            <xad:SigPolicyId>
                                <xad:Identifier>1234567</xad:Identifier>
                                <xad:Description>Description de la politique de signature numérique</xad:Description>
                            </xad:SigPolicyId>
                            <xad:SigPolicyHash>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>ZXphcmxramhxZGY=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </xad:SigPolicyHash>
                            <xad:SigPolicyQualifiers>
                                <xad:SigPolicyQualifier>
                                    <xad:SPURI>1234567</xad:SPURI>
                                </xad:SigPolicyQualifier>
                            </xad:SigPolicyQualifiers>
                        </xad:SignaturePolicyId>
                    </xad:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                    <xad:SignerRole>
                        <xad:ClaimedRoles/>
                    </xad:SignerRole>
                </xad:SignedSignatureProperties>
                <xad:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                    <xad:CommitmentTypeIndication>
                        <xad:CommitmentTypeId>
                            <xad:Identifier>1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.6.1</xad:Identifier>
                            <xad:Description>1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.6.1</xad:Description>
                        </xad:CommitmentTypeId>
                        <xad:ObjectReference>#D0-Reference</xad:ObjectReference>
                    </xad:CommitmentTypeIndication>
                </xad:SignedDataObjectProperties>
            </xad:SignedProperties>
```

(I indented it on purpose, at start, its linear XML).

I need to obtain the following Digest :

```
<ds:Reference Id="Sig_20151117_172752_SP-Reference" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/#SignedProperties" URI="#Sig_20151117_172752_SP">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>euEROs8DacsBe3xqXBY5T+M07AI=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
```

I'm using Canonicalization C14N to do so.

I tried to add those namespaces into the first tag :

xmlns:xad="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"

In the following orders :

Or

But none of those attempts would work. Is there something missing ? (Here's the C# method I use to calculate the SHA-1 Digest :

```
public string CalculateHashSHA1(string input)
        {
            using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                return Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
            }
        }
```

EDIT :

- the source file is here : https://1fichier.com/?y9spk6g2zk
- the source file with indentation is there : https://1fichier.com/?11r0i8izzt

I'm trying to obtain this digest : euEROs8DacsBe3xqXBY5T+M07AI=

Comment: Are you sure your data is the same as the data in that combined xml? (that is, the xml is just a descriptor of a signature; not the original data)

Comment: I added my source file in the end of my post, I'm still not finding the same digest.

Comment: Ok what you're dealing with here is XADES, there are a couple of .net libraries available that will let you do that.

Comment: In fact, the Canonicalization method I used was incorrect. I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I needed to use this method :

```
XmlDsigExcC14NTransform innerTransform = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform(false);
```

And the result is correct.